# How to create a button that interacts with texts

Tags: html

I was trying to write my code here but for whatever reason the site prohibited me to. My code is essentially two texts with a button in the middle. Whatever you write in the first text it will be copied to the other text once you hit the button. I want to edit the code so that it does what it does and ALSO accepts values from the second text and copies to the first one. Thanks.

```
<html> 
<head> <meta charset="utf-8">  </head> 
<body> 
<input type="text" value="" id="from" /> 
<button onclick="document.getElementById('to').value = document.getElementById('from').value">copy</button>
 <input type="text" value="" id="to" /> 
</body> </html>
```

Comment: "I was trying to write my code here but for whatever reason the site prohibited me to." Typically, if you put it into the correct code formatting format (4 spaces at the beginning of every line) it will be less likely to be rejected by the post quality filter.

Comment: This is my code... What should i modify exactly?                               <html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>
  <input type="text" value="" id="from" />
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('to').value = 
   document.getElementById('from').value">copy</button>
  <input type="text" value="" id="to" />
 </body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

Use an on change for each of the text boxes.  I'm a jQuery user but if you did it with standard JS you could do something like ... this is not full code ...

```
<textarea id='t1' name='t1' onChange="document.getElementbyId('t2').value=document.getElementbyId('t2').value"></textarea>
<textarea id='t2' name='t2' onChange="document.getElementbyId('t1').value=document.getElementbyId('t2').value">
</textarea>
```

Clicking the button would also trigger the change event.  If you want it to copy the contents ONLY when the button is clicked, you could set a variable that stores the textarea id last changed and use that to determine which way to do the copy when the button is clicked.